# IE support for vega

Tags: vega

Vega seems to intend to compile away both `...` and `=>`. This is not supported in IE11 browser. Anything can be fixed to support IE11 browser?
We are using in angular 7 projects but it fails on module load for IE.

Comment: Vega has a page [Supporting Internet Explorer](https://vega.github.io/vega/usage/internet-explorer/) that describes what problems can arise. And your first should figure out where exactly the problem is. Create a minimal Vega only code and run it in IE to see if you get it running. And add more and more features until it fails.

Answer (score 0):

As described in Vega's [Supporting Internet Explorer](https://vega.github.io/vega/usage/internet-explorer/) page, Vega does not directly support Internet Explorer. However, you can use a transpiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) as part of your application build process to transform the resulting code and target a wider range of browsers / platforms.